# What is the logic behind the boot process

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I’m trying to understand the logic so I can replace Mac partition with Ubuntu.

The way I understand it is the MBR is read first, and started. Then the signature of the GPT table is tested and if present it is used to boot the computer.

Is GRUB replaces the MBR so the computer boots in Linux?

So what happening with dual-boot?  Is GRUB put back the old MBR and GPT so Windows can boot?

I need to understand this so I can somehow « copy » my Ubuntu USB drive over the MAC OS, and keep Windows 10/Ubuntu as dual-boot.
Thanks

Comment: Grub is a boot loader.  When you install Ubuntu as a dual boot system, grub takes over the Windows boot loader.  There is no switching back and forth, grub boots either Ubuntu or Windows or another OS.  On older Windows systems, Windows updates could sometimes over write grub and you had to re-install grub to boot back into Ubuntu.  Never change MBR to GPT partitions with an OS on them, unless you want to lose data.

Comment: I suggest you read `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table` , `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI` . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll read...

Comment: @waltinator Thanks.  I already read them all but the power-on_self-test yesterday.  ;-)